# Javascript Array = Adding in missing dates

Tags: javascript, loops, jscript

I have some data of our bike shop sales throughout the day, and we are pushing that data through a loop to build up an array.

Our code looks like

```
var sales_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data_feed.length; i++)
{
    var sales_values = Object.values(data_feed[i]);
    sales_values = sales_values[0].split(";");
    var date = sales_values[0];

    var sales = sales_values[10];
    if(sales != '') { sales_array.push(date+','+sales); }
}
```

And this works great, with an output looking something like

```
"2022-02-07T16:20:00+00:00,20"
"2022-02-08T09:18:00+00:00,4500"
"2022-02-08T14:25:00+00:00,210"
"2022-02-09T11:21:00+00:00,100"
```

The problem is, if there's a couple of days when the shop is closed and no sales take place, we end up with missing dates in our output

For example, on the 27th Feb we were open, but on the 28th and 1st we were closed, and reopened on the 2nd, so we ended up with

```
"2022-02-27T16:45:00+00:00,3000"
"2022-02-27T17:10:00+00:00,450"
-----MISSING-----
"2022-03-02T08:29:00+00:00,1000"
"2022-03-02T15:54:00+00:00,550"
```

How can we change our loop code, so even if there is a date missing, it'll add it in with a 0 sale value, so the above would look like

```
"2022-02-27T16:45:00+00:00,3000"
"2022-02-27T17:10:00+00:00,450"
"2022-02-28T00:00:00+00:00,0"
"2022-03-01T00:00:00+00:00,0"
"2022-03-02T08:29:00+00:00,1000"
"2022-03-02T15:54:00+00:00,550"
```

Comment: Please make sure that you include a minimal reproduction of the code such that we can run it and test the behavior to ensure we provide you with an answer that satisfies you.

Answer (score 0):

add these code

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(noOfDays){
    var tmpDate = new Date(this.valueOf());
    tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + noOfDays);
    return tmpDate;
}

var sort = sales_array.map(e => e.split(',')[0]).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))

for (var i = new Date(sort[0]).addDays(1); i < new Date(sort[sort.length-1]); i = i.addDays(1))
{
    sales_array.push(i.toISOString().split('T')[0]+'T00:00:00+00:00,0');
}

sales_array = sales_array.sort((a, b) => a.split(',')[0].localeCompare(b.split(',')[0]))
```

```js
var data_feed = [
  { a: '2022-02-27T17:10:00+00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;450' },
  { a: '2022-03-02T08:29:00+00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1000' }
]

var sales_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data_feed.length; i++)
{
    var sales_values = Object.values(data_feed[i]);
    sales_values = sales_values[0].split(";");
    var date = sales_values[0];

    var sales = sales_values[10];
    if(sales != '') { sales_array.push(date+','+sales); }
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(noOfDays){
    var tmpDate = new Date(this.valueOf());
    tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + noOfDays);
    return tmpDate;
}

var sort = sales_array.map(e => e.split(',')[0]).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))

for (var i=new Date(sort[0]).addDays(1); i < new Date(sort[sort.length-1]); i=i.addDays(1))
{
    sales_array.push(i.toISOString().split('T')[0]+'T00:00:00+00:00,0');
}

sales_array = sales_array.sort((a,b) => a.split(',')[0].localeCompare(b.split(',')[0]))

console.log(sales_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

asumming `data_feed` variable like

```
var data_feed = [
{value: "2022-02-07T16:20:00+00:00;;;;;;;;;;20"},
{value: "2022-02-08T09:18:00+00:00;;;;;;;;;;4500"},
{value: "2022-02-10T14:25:00+00:00;;;;;;;;;;210"},
{value: "2022-02-13T11:21:00+00:00;;;;;;;;;;100"}
]
```

i added some codes inside yours

```
var sales_array = [];
var next_current_ymd; // store expected 'next ymd' for compare with in next index
for (var i = 0; i < data_feed.length; i++)
{
    var sales_values = Object.values(data_feed[i]);
    sales_values = sales_values[0].split(";");
    var date = sales_values[0];
    
    // me added - start
    var current_ymd = date.substring(0,10);
    
    // next_current_ymd <= 'missing date' you explained < current_ymd
    // loop 'missing date' sequentially until current date
    // skipped first time because 'next_current_ymd' is null
    for(;next_current_ymd < current_ymd;){
        
        sales_array.push(next_current_ymd + 'T00:00:00+00:00,0');

        // next_current_ymd + 1
        var next_d = new Date(next_current_ymd);
        next_d.setUTCDate(next_d.getUTCDate() + 1);
        next_current_ymd = next_d.toISOString().substr(0,10);
    }
    
    // steor 'expected next ymd'
    var d = new Date(current_ymd);
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);
    next_current_ymd = d.toISOString().substr(0,10);

    // me added - end
  
    var sales = sales_values[10];
    if(sales != '') { sales_array.push(date+','+sales); }
}
console.log(sales_array);
```

results:

```
[
    "2022-02-07T16:20:00+00:00,20",
    "2022-02-08T09:18:00+00:00,4500",
    "2022-02-09T00:00:00+00:00,0",
    "2022-02-10T14:25:00+00:00,210",
    "2022-02-11T00:00:00+00:00,0",
    "2022-02-12T00:00:00+00:00,0",
    "2022-02-13T11:21:00+00:00,100"
]
```